# Limit object properties to keyof interface

Tags: typescript

this code won't compile:

```
interface IFoo {
   a: number;
}

type TFoo = keyof IFoo;
type OFoo = { [key: TFoo]: any };

let obj: OFoo = { a: 1 };
```

What I'm trying to achieve is for obj to only be assignable with object with valid properties, as if I wrote:

```
let obj: IFoo = { a: 1};
```

but I need to do it by keyof.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

While you can't directly use anything but `string` or `number` as the key type in an index signature (and your definition of `OFoo` will give you an error to that effect), you *can* restrict keys to a subtype of `string` using [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types). Since `TFoo`, a.k.a. `keyof Foo`, is a subtype of `string`, you can use a mapped type like this:

```
type OFoo = { [K in TFoo]: any };
```

Note that the syntax for mapped types differs from that of regular index signatures.  The `TFoo` above corresponds to the type of allowable keys, which is just `"a"` in your case, but could also be a union of string literals like `"a"|"b"|"c"`, or even `string`.  And the `K` above is a parameter which corresponds to the *type* of key for each property.  (You don't really care about `K` since the type for each property *value* is `any` and has nothing to do with `K`, but you could have used `K` to pick out particular properties if you wanted to.)  Anyway, let's use it:

```
let obj: OFoo = { a: 1 }; // okay
let obj = { }; // error, property 'a' is missing
let obj = { c: 1 }; // error, excess property 'c'
```

---

By the way, I'd probably use the built-in standard library type `Record<K,T>` which is defined like this:

```
type Record<K extends string, T> = {
  [P in K]: T
}
```

Or, you can think: "a `Record<K, T>` is an object where every key is in `K` and every value is a `T`".  And for you, `K` is `TFoo`, and `T` is `any`:

```
type OFoo = Record<TFoo, any>;  // same thing
```

---

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: It should be `type OFoo = { [key in TFoo]: IFoo[key] };`, otherwise `let obj: OFoo = { a: 'hey' };` would be type compatible.

Comment: Great you are mentioning `Record` in the answer, such built-in types are easy to overlook!