# Access unitiliazied TypeScript field

Tags: typescript

I have a JavaScript class that loads data asynchronously, but I would like to extract a property from the

```
interface Header {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

class RecordWithHeader {
    header: PossiblyUninitialized<Header> = {};

    constructor(private dataService) { }

    loadData() {
        this.dataService.getHeader()
            .then((header: Header) => this.header = header);
    }

    print() {
        // want to print possibly undefined value without checking if initialized
        console.log('The id is', this.header.id);
    }
}
```

I have tried several ways to define `PossiblyUninitialized` but cannot get the accessor to work without using any.

### Attempt 1: Key of map

```
type PossiblyUninitialized<T> = T | { [key in keyof T]: undefined };
```

> Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'PossiblyUninitialized'.
>
> Type '{}' is not assignable to type '{ id: undefined; name: undefined; }'.
>
> Property 'id' is missing in type '{}'.

This throws an error when trying to assign the empty object to the property. This is related to [this keyof question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47181789/4252741).

### Attempt 2: Basic map

```
type PossiblyUninitialized<T> = T | { [key: string]: undefined };
```

> Property 'id' does not exist on type 'PossiblyUninitialized'.
>
> Property 'id' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]: undefined; }'.

```
type PossiblyUninitialized<T> = T | { [key: string]: any };
```

> Property 'id' does not exist on type 'PossiblyUninitialized'.
>
> Property 'id' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]: any; }'.

This was an attempt to use a simpler map that didn't have the `keyof` restriction. But TypeScript did not like the property accessor.
Note: This would work with `console.log('ID', this.header['id'])` but that is not what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

So it does not seem possible to have TypeScript handle this use case using only type annotations. You can, however, use type casting to force TypeScript to understand the empty object.

Using the type

```
type PossiblyUninitialized<T> = T | { [key in keyof T]: undefined };
```

Or defined using TypeScript's `Record` type

```
type PossiblyUninitialized<T> = T | Record<keyof T, undefined>;
```

The header property can then be defined by casting into that type.

```
header = <PossiblyUninitialized<Header>> {};
```

or in the TSX compatible way

```
header = {} as PossiblyUninitialized<Header>;
```

This preserves syntax highlighting for the header properties. Additionally, if you have strict null checks turned on, TypeScript will identify the `id` property as of type `number | undefined` and the `name` property as `string | undefined`. To see this working, [view it in the TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Header%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20type%20PossiblyUninitialized%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20%7C%20%7B%5Bkey%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20undefined%20%7D%3B%0D%0Atype%20PossiblyUninitialized%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20%7C%20Record%3Ckeyof%20T%2C%20undefined%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20RecordWithHeader%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20header%20%3D%20%3CPossiblyUninitialized%3CHeader%3E%3E%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20header%20%3D%20%7B%7D%20as%20PossiblyUninitialized%3CHeader%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20dataService%3A%20any)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20loadData()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.dataService.getHeader()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.then((header%3A%20Header)%20%3D%3E%20this.header%20%3D%20header)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20print()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20want%20to%20print%20possibly%20undefined%20value%20without%20checking%20if%20initialized%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('The%20id%20is'%2C%20this.header.id)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing what you need is the following:

```
type PossiblyUninitialized<T> = { [key in keyof T]?: T[key] };
```